# Find all integer solutions to $x^2+4=y^3$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, contest-math, elliptic-curves

Find all integer solutions to $x^2+4=y^3$.

Some obvious solutions are $(x,y)=(\pm2,2)$. Are these the only ones?

Comment: You forgot the tag *elliptic-curves*. Regards.

Comment: Yes. Good point. :)

Answer (score 8):

These are examples of Mordell's equation. The only solutions are $(\pm 2,2)$ and $(\pm 11,5)$ to equation $x^2+4 = y^3$. [The same problem is discussed in theorem $3.3$ on page $6$ here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf). The article, by Keith Conrad, is a wonderful article on solutions to certain Mordell's equation and is worth reading.

Comment: Indeed a good note: his method for dealing with such curves is quite consistent, and tends more to algebraic methods than elliptic curves. And I think it is relatively difficult to adapt the elliptic viewpoint here.

Comment: @awllower Yes. Only a basic calculus background is needed to understand, all the equations solved in the article.

Comment: A calculus background?!?  There's no calculus used at that link.  Rather, one should know basic number theory (e.g., when $2 \bmod p$ is a square and how factoring and norms are related in ${\mathbf Z}[i]$).

Comment: @KCD Maybe that means *calculus* to user 17762? Like calculus and number-theort are both too elementary to be distinguished? Just saying, anyway.:D